# Generate random bytearray from a distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random-data

I am looking for a way to generate random bytes sampled from specified underlying distribution. e.g. bytes generated from a normal distribution with given mean and variance, bytes generated from poisson distribution with specified lambda and so on.

I've used `numpy.random.bytes(...)` as far the documentation mentions, it generates **random** bytes which I presume are sampled from uniform distribution. However, I want a numpy based snippet to generate specified number of bytes from possibly any of the specified distributions listed [numpy sampling distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions)

Comment: Showing more code would be helpful here. Where did you get the idea to use `numpy.random.bytes`?

Comment: `numpy.random.bytes` from [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.bytes.html#numpy.random.bytes]

Comment: @jvars: Mark wasn't asking for the documentation link, he wanted to know your thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate random values within the range [0, 256) or normalize them to that range (by multiplication, subtraction or addition) and then truncate the results to `uint8` integers.That result can then be converted to bytes.

E.g., generating a normal (Gaussian) distribution around the midpoint:

```
values = np.random.normal(128, 35, size=32)
as_bytes = values.astype(np.uint8).tobytes()
```

Take into account that not all random distributions are suitable for expression in a series of 0-255 integers.